# Variation of gamma line broadening with time of the source

Tags: radioactivity, gamma-rays

What explains the broadening of the gamma linewidth as the source "gets old"?

I have been using Iron-57 in my radiation studies but the source I obtained 6 months ago shows significant line broadening now. What explains this increase in line width as the source decays?

Answer (score 0):

The linewidth of a gamma source does not broaden as the source ages. Are you sure you are calculating the width of the line properly? As the source gets older, the gamma line becomes smaller relative to the background. To the eye, that looks as if the gamma line became wider. This is however not the case, as a proper fit with proper modeling of the background will confirm.